# Как настроить 3proxy на Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi

Подскажите пожалуйста есть Raspberry Pi 4 с raspbian +3proxy на неё заходит интернет по витой паре из маршрутизатора и так же подключен 4G модем, определяется как сетевая карта в итоге имеем esp0(интернет от кабеля 192.168.88.1) и esp1(наш 4g 192.168.12.1)

мне нужно чтобы при обращение к esp0 переключало на esp1, но когда я запускаю 3proxy трафик через 4g модем не идёт

я думаю что проблема где то в маршрутизации самой raspbian подскажите пожалуйста куда копать

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vk9jcy

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vk9k2n

Comment: вот то что в маршрутах